# ssh - Connection reset by peer

Tags: linux, ssh

Yesterday I connected to a server(Linux) very well.
But today I have to connect to another server(Linux) because of some reasons.

However I have an error:

```
~/Desktop $ ssh -vvv [username]@[serverIP]
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to sysp [serverIP] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/yoo/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/yoo/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/yoo/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/yoo/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/yoo/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/yoo/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/yoo/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/yoo/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

I've read some posts about this. But there was no solution to me.

The servers are not in my control. So I can't access the server and use the console of server.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The person who can most likely help you is the administrator of this system, or any firewalling devices in front of it.

Comment: @user4556274 is this because of firewall?

Comment: quite possibly.  The debug messages show that you make no connection to the remote server--they are all the local client messages preparatory to establishing the connection.  Immediately on attempting to communicate with the server you are disconnected.

Comment: How old is your ssh client? Please read this http://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=15626

Comment: @Matputer I don't think this is because of a firewall.  There is in fact a "Connection established" (read, at a minimum TCP handshake completed), and then the connection is reset.  A firewall would simply deny the connection in an unequivocal way and no handshake would complete.

Comment: @goldilocks, how do you know a TCP handshake was completed?  The error printed indicates `ECONNRESET`.  Couldn't that come from an interrupted handshake `SYN > RST,ACK` ?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I'm using iTerm2 on mac os. how can I get the version of ssh? `$ ssh -v localhost` say `OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8`.

Comment: @goldilocks so what is the problem? It's just my ssh problem?

Comment: @user4556274 You could be right, but I think ECONNRESET is an error that will occur when you try to use an fd that's already been successfully submitted to `connect()` (which is where the handshake completes).  It means the other side arbitrarily closed the connection (with outgoing packets pending?) and will happen on a `read()` (maybe..) or `write()` (definitely) using the fd.  It could mean that, e.g., **it is actually not an SSH server on the port.**

Comment: Have you ever found out what was it? similar problem here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391125/jumphost-suddenly-reseting-first-ssh-connection-attempts